# Меню с помощью flex

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, меню

Есть меню в шапке сайта. Каждый элемент меню занимает определенную часть в %. При уменьшении размера экрана меню сжимается, **при этом элементы меню сохраняют свой размер в %**.

1. Как это реализовать с помощью flex?
2. Как к примеру реализовать меню с шапки сайта с [макета Фигмы](https://www.figma.com/file/M48y67TLYWAxG4l94tWa9X/Estate?node-id=4%3A2)?
3. Как реализовать меню с шапки сайта [2-й тип меню с Фигмы](https://www.figma.com/file/rLh5UzMWwzP8undBO6FeqH/Outdoor?node-id=0%3A1)?

Comment: Что-бы кто-то мог вам помось добавьте вам код, вж)

Comment: @ПростаMiha  с кодом пока что проблемы. Есть материал для реализации.

Comment: Насколько я знаю макет делается для разных размеров экранов, например 1920, 1020, 720, и 320. Довольно сложно сделать адаптивное сайт только с одним макетом

Comment: @ПростаMiha выбирайте брейкпойнты и расстояние между элементами интерфейса на свое усмотрение, а именно расстояние между логотипом меню и телом меню.

Comment: @ПростаMiha Я имею ввиду расстояния между элементами при меньшем разрешении. Можете устанавливать их на свое усмотрение.